# How to share a variable between error and success callback of angular http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

i want to share a variable between both methods of $http.get request of angular js
my code looks like this

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$http) {
$rootScope.checkSession = function(){
  window.a = false;
    $http.get('/data/url')
    .success(function(response) {
      window.a = true;
    })
    .error(function(response){
      window.a = false;
    });
    return window.a;
};
});
```

and my controller code looks like this

```
app.controller('profileController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
   alert($rootScope.checkSession());
});
```

it is always output false while if i alert response in both functions it works fine.

Comment: window.a is returned before success or error comes.. this is wrong approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your are doing is not the correct way of dealing with asynchronous call, as per current implementation it will always return `false` from that `checkSession` method. You need to return `promise` from that method which dealing with asynchronously. That promise will return data from its `resolve` & `reject`.

Additional thing is, I would love to have this code inside a factory, rather than having in inside `$rootScope`.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('sessionFactory', function($http) {
  var sessionFactory = {}
  sessionFactory.checkSession = function(){
    return $http.get('/data/url')
    .then(function(response) {
      return true;
    },(function(response){
      return false;
    });
  };
  return sessionFactory;
});
```

So for using it in controller, you 1st need to inject `sessionFactory` on your controller factory function & then use `checkSession` method on it. Inside .then of that method you will have returned data.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('profileController', function($scope, sessionFactory) {
   sessionFactory.checkSession().then(function(data){
      alert(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: good example, just be aware that alert() probably won't work correctly with the promise.

Comment: @Maarten look at edit..Actually I was converting it to factory..to make that `checkSession` method rather than pollution `$rootScope`

Comment: @VivekMaru do look at updated which has better explaination... Glad to help you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing returns and promises. The window.a will be set async at the time your promise ($http.get) resolves, and by that time your return with the initial value has already been returned and used by alert().